# Верстка писем / В gmail почте добавляется увеличение изображения, как убрать

Tags: css3, вёрстка, email, вёрстка-email, табличная-верстка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, что б при открытии письма в gmail почте не добавлялась возможность масштабирования изображения как на рисунке ниже
[image: Изображение в gmail почте]

Код верстки письма

```html
<img class="game_desc" alt="Netgame Entertainment game" src="games.png" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; clear: both; display: block; max-width: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; width: auto; border=0; border: none; @media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {display:none;}">
```

Из-за чего это возникает? На маленьких изображениях всё ок.

Comment: уже пробовал и в атрибутах height прописывать. Не помогает

Comment: border=0 это надо убрать наверное

Comment: убрал. Это не помогло. Всё равно увеличивает